# Twitter feed won't load on sub page

Tags: jquery, twitter, feed

I try to load a Twitter feed (using the settings by Twitter) on my webpage.

On the main page everything works fine and the Twitter feed pops up. But as soon as I go to the subpage (using jQuery load) it just shows the alternative text as a link.

I figured out, that the Twitter feed will load, when I load the subpage directly within the document ready function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#content').load('subpage.html');
 });
```

But as soon as I go to the same subpage manually (using the link in my navigation bar), there's just the alternative text again. My navigation bar uses the following function to load the subpage:

```
function show_content(id) {
      $('#content').load(id);
 };
```

In a nutshell:

1. The Twitter feed loads fine on the index.html page
2. The Twitter feed loads fine when I load the subpage in document.ready
3. The Twitter feed **does not** load when I go to the subpage via my navbar

Help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

/edit: I assume it's because of the .load()....When I open the site directly via url the twitter feed pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the code provided on this site: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading

Then using

```
<script>twttr.widgets.load();</script>
```

on every subpage where I want to load a twitter feed.